# Dynamically query pandas df for values of column with multiple conditions on other column being True

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like this:

| Animal | Zoo |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | Berlin |
| Lion | Munich |
| Lion | Paris |
| Monkey | Berlin |
| Monkey | Munich |
| Monkey | Rotterdam |
| Bat | Berlin |
| Goose | Rotterdam |
| Tiger | Paris |
| Tiger | Munich |

I am looking for a way to dynamically build a query which returns the unique values of animals which appear in a specific set of zoos, e.g. all animals which are located in the zoos in Berlin AND Munich.

The result should look like this:

```
result = ['Lion', 'Monkey']
```

So far I tried this

```
# # initialize list of lists
data = [
        ['Lion', 'Berlin'], ['Lion', 'Munich'], ['Lion', 'Paris'],
        ['Monkey', 'Berlin'], ['Monkey', 'Munich'], ['Monkey', 'Rotterdam'],
        ['Bat', 'Berlin'],
        ['Goose', 'Rotterdam'],
        ['Tiger', 'Paris'], ['Tiger', 'Munich']
]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Animal', 'Zoo'])

# filter df
df_filtered = df.query(" (`Zoo` == 'Berlin' | `Zoo` == 'Munich')")

# get animals as list
result = df_filtered['Animal'].unique().tolist()

# print list of results
print(result)
```

which gives me the animals which appear in  Berlin OR Munich.

```
['Lion', 'Monkey', 'Bat', 'Tiger']
```

Turning the OR into an AND statement leads to an empty dataframe:

```
df.query(" (`Zoo` == 'Berlin' & `Zoo` == 'Munich')")
```

Comment: Can you put your current code in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groubby:

```
result = df.groupby('Animal').filter(lambda x: set(['Berlin', 'Munich']).issubset(set(x['Zoo']))).Animal.unique().tolist()
```

Output:
 
['Lion', 'Monkey']

Answer (score 0):

To get animals that are present in both zoos you would need to filter the initial dataset by those zoos and filter groups of animals by matching 2 required zoos:

```
zoos = {'Berlin', 'Munich'}
df[df.Zoo.isin(zoos)].groupby('Animal').filter(lambda x: x['Zoo'].nunique() == 2)
```

---

```
    Animal     Zoo
0    Lion   Berlin
1    Lion   Munich
3  Monkey   Berlin
4  Monkey   Munich
```